# .Net int() equivalent in PHP

Tags: .net, php

I'm converting a .net app to php.  What would be the php equivalent of `int(6.22555445656)` in php?

Comment: That is not valid in C#. What language are you using?

Comment: probably VB, int() is basically Math.floor()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php ??

Comment: the interval() function was what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused--do you mean intval() is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This should clear it up:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$arr = array(-6, -6.2, -6.7, 5, 5.3, 5.8);
foreach ($arr as $v) {
  printf("%f: (int) = %d, floor = %d, ceil = %d\n", $v, (int)$v, floor($v), ceil($v));
}
?>
```

outputs:

```
-6.000000: (int) = -6, floor = -6, ceil = -6
-6.200000: (int) = -6, floor = -7, ceil = -6
-6.700000: (int) = -6, floor = -7, ceil = -6
5.000000: (int) = 5, floor = 5, ceil = 5
5.300000: (int) = 5, floor = 5, ceil = 6
5.800000: (int) = 5, floor = 5, ceil = 6
```

**Note:** Casting to int and [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) do *different things*.

**Edit:** Oh, you want to convert from a string to an int. One piece of advice: when you ask questions like these, describe what the original function does. You'll get a quicker and clearer answer.

Also, bear in mind that types in PHP and .Net work different. For example:

```
$foo = '-234'; // string
$bar = $foo + 5;
print $bar; // -229
```

PHP has a complex [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) system to automatically convert the type of variables as required. This includes going to and from booleans, integers, floats and strings as required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what your goal is. But you can try

```
$var = (int) 6.22555445656;
print $var; // 6
```

Also see [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval)